# How to build a library for both Android and IOS?

Tags: android, ios, shared-libraries

I have a piece of code of ANSI C (only use libc in it). I want to make it a library to use in both Android (with JNI encapsulation) and IOS.

Is it possible to do? If it does, how to set the build environment?

Should it be build twice for each platform? I am totally new for cross-platform compile. Maybe the question is stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. You can probably use it as is in XCode.
For Java, you will need to build an `.so` library using the NDK. It may be painful, depending on how ANSI it really is and how much of the standard libraries you use. see http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html